# Do x86 applications use 64 bits addresses in x64 operative systems?

Tags: memory, 64-bit, operating-systems, 32-bit

I was wondering... 64bits OSs can run 32bits applications right? Windows use WoW64 to achieve this right?

My question is, when these applications are run, does they use 64bits or 32bits addresses? I was wondering this because of the memory usage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, every program sees about 2GB of memory space (there is flag one can set to get 3GB) and therefore never has to need 64-bit pointers (32-bit pointers will work fine). The OS can handle all the 64-bit real memory management under the hood.

Not quite sure what this has to do with memory usage.

Comment: Because 64bits programs uses more memory because they need 64bits pointers.

Comment: That is such a tiny tiny difference that it does not matter (32 bits per pointer). In addition, to actually get used, the pointers the program uses have to be converted to the 64-bit real addresses anyway, so it does not prevent a 64-bit address from being stored.

Comment: @soandos, while it is true that for an individual *application* the difference in pointer size will affect the memory footprint minimally. On the os side - the 64 bit pointer increase will quadruple the size of the page table required. Page tables on a loaded 32 bit system can reach 50MB, quadrupling that is not a small difference.

Comment: @crasic it quadruples the maximum size, not the actual size.

Comment: @soandos assuming we keep the same page size (of course that is a maybe) it will quadruple the current page table size. Think about it logically - if we pad pointer in our 32bit PT with 0's just for the hell of it it will at least quadruple in size (assuming a flat PT, which is reasonable enough for a size approximation)

Comment: If the number of pages stays the same, page size doubles.

Comment: You are forgetting that every page table entry has both a virtual part and a real part, both will be doubled when going from a 32 bit system to a 64 bit system (actually a little more because with 4KB pages we are masking the last 12 bits, so we are really going from 24 bits to 52bits in the PT a factor of 2.16). However you right that if we are using 32bit VA to 64 bit PA to begin with then the total change will be only be  two fold

Comment: Minor Correction: If you set the program flag ("Large Address Aware") on a 32bit (x86) executable, and run under a 64bit (x64) version of Windows, it will get 4GB address space. (No OS boot flag is needed.) This means that 32bit programs that need lots of address space do better on a 64bit OS.

Comment: You are not correct on either count. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487508) for the fact that it is 3GB, and 4GB is still within reach of a 32bit pointer.

Comment: @crasic _"You are forgetting that every page table entry has both a virtual part and a real part"_ This does not describe any page table entry format I've ever seen. What you're calling the "virtual part" is derived from the virtual address being translated. It isn't stored in the PTE. And PTE size has already doubled by going to PAE, which almost all Windows systems are running these days even if they're 32-bit; they have to be to have NX enabled.

Comment: @soandos yes, Richard is correct. You can demo this easily with `testlimit64` from the Windows Internals book tools, available from the sysinternals site. The article you linked is not referring to 64-bit systems.

Comment: @crasic your numbers are way off. On a 32-bit system, even with PAE enabled, one eight-byte PTE defines a 4K page. So with 4 GiB of v.a.s. you have 8 MiB of PTEs maximum, not 50. Where did you get 50 MB? And just like v.a.s., the page tables do not have to be completely populated; they act like a sparse array. Where you have a 4K page completely unused, you have a zero PTE. If you have an entire PT worth of unused pages (2 MiB of v.a.s.) that PT does not exist at all and there is a zero PDE. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

32 bit applications can only see 32 bit addresses.  WoW64 simulates the 32 bit environment inside the 64 bit memory space for 32 bit applications.

Comment: So the 32bits application uses the same amount of memory it would use in a 32bits environment?

Comment: I dont know the exact answer, so im venturing a guess.  The applications themselves would probably use the same amount of memory in a 64 bit environment as they would in a 32 bit environment.  However, more memory is used to by WoW64 in order to map those environments.

Comment: Keltari's answer, and comment, are correct. More: A 32-bit app running on 64-bit Windows flatly _cannot_ use 64-bit addresses or pointers, nor access the 64-bit-wide versions of the processor's registers. There simply is no way in the 32-bit x86 instruction coding to express such things.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific since you don't distinguish between virtual memory address and physical memory addresses.

Yes, x86 programs are going to use more memory and resources. They will have a 32 bit virtual address space, but underneath, the Memory Manager (MM or MMM) will use x64 pointers. Not like that takes a whole lot of effort though.

By far the biggest resource cost is drivers.  There were some substantial kernel changes, many due to security, that required large parts of drivers to be rewritten.

> Internally, every program sees about 2GB of memory space (there is flag one can set to get 3GB) and therefore never has to need 64-bit pointers (32-bit pointers will work fine). The OS can handle all the 64-bit real memory management under the hood.

I believe this is untrue.  Every program sees 4GB (32 bit virtual address space) but the kernel splits the physical address space in half.  The two 2GB you are familiar with refers to the physical memory address.

Comment: This answer deserves an upvote since it is the only one that mentions the salient terms *virtual* and *physical* memory addresses.  Other answers that try to explain relationships between userspace memory and memory management without specifying the memory space of the pointer or address are vague and probably misleading.

Comment: Surfasb: Sorry, but you are mistaken. The kernel does not "split the physical address space in half." The "two 2GB" refers to the default user vs. kernel mode split of _virtual_ address space in 32-bit Windows. In 64-bit Windows, a 32-bit process does potentially have access to 4 GB v.a.s., but its binaries must all have the "large address aware" flag in order to use this; otherwise it will be constrained to the first 2 GB of v.a.s.

Comment: Regarding driver porting: If proper data types have been used, most drivers port from x86 Windows to x64 simply by rebuilding. Nor did drivers need substantial changes for security in _any_ Windows version. Drivers in Windows operate well below the security layers: I/O requests are checked for security violations (ACLs on files or devices, memory access, etc.) before they ever get to the driver; security is just not the driver's job. Even for file system drivers, while the FSD has the job of storing and retrieving the OS's security info, the actual checking is done elsewhere.